# Using Django class_prepared signal

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract model class responsible for custom validation procedures and a bunch of models in different apps which inherits from this class. And I'm trying to use `class_prepared` signal to import some app dependent validators, like that:

```py
def on_class_prepared(sender, **kw):
    if issubclass(sender, DefaultModel):
        try:
            getattr(sender, 'class_prepared')(**kw)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
class_prepared.connect(on_class_prepared)


class ValidatableModel(DefaultModel):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def class_prepared(cls, **kw):
        # knowing cls.__module__
        # here we can import application dependent validators
```

So now particular `class_prepared` methods will be invoked once, when apache or whatever starts. Am i right?

Comment: Roughly, yes, though there are exceptions. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works pretty well. What kind of exceptions you found?